# giving duplicate values unique identifiers in spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was hoping somebody might know a simple solution to this problem using spark and scala.

I have some network data of animal movements in the following format (currently in a dataframe in spark):

```
id  start end   date
12  0     10    20091017
12  10    20    20091201
12  20    0     20091215
12  0     15    20100220
12  15    0     20100320
```

the id is the id of the animal, the start and end are locations of movements (i.e. the second row is movement from location id 10 to location id 20). If the start or end is a 0 that means the animal is born or has died (i.e. first row animal 12 is born and row 3 the animal has died).

The problem I have is that the data was collected so that animal ID's were re-used in the database so after an animal has died its id may re-occur.

What I want to do is apply a unique tag to all movements which are re-used. So you would get a database something like

```
id  start end   date
12a 0     10    20091017
12a 10    20    20091201
12a 20    0     20091215
12b 0     15    20100220
12b 15    0     20100320
```

I've been trying a few different approaches but can't seem to get anything that works. The database is very large (several gigabytes) so need something that works quite efficiently.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution that may work relatively well directly on `DataFrames` is to use window functions but I still wouldn't expect particularly high performance here:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq(
  (12,  0, 10, 20091017), (12,  10, 20, 20091201),
  (12,  20, 0, 20091215), (12,  0, 15, 20100220),
  (12,  15, 0, 20100320)
).toDF("id", "start", "end", "date")

val w = Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"date")
val uniqueId = struct(
  $"id", sum(when($"start" === 0, 1).otherwise(0)).over(w))

df.withColumn("unique_id", uniqueId).show

// +---+-----+---+--------+---------+
// | id|start|end|    date|unique_id|
// +---+-----+---+--------+---------+
// | 12|    0| 10|20091017|   [12,1]|
// | 12|   10| 20|20091201|   [12,1]|
// | 12|   20|  0|20091215|   [12,1]|
// | 12|    0| 15|20100220|   [12,2]|
// | 12|   15|  0|20100320|   [12,2]|
// +---+-----+---+--------+---------+
```